# Range Slider Multiple Color Track

Tags: android, androidx, material-components-android, rangeslider

I'm using a range slider (com.google.android.material.slider.RangeSlider) with three thumb sliders.  As such the bar is broken up into 4 segments.  The first with values below any of the thumbs, 2 segments between the thumbs, and a segment with values greater than any of the thumbs.

The range slider has a track color property (app:trackColor) you can set to change what color the track is.  This however applies to the entire bar.  I'm looking to set each of the 4 segments of the bar to a different color.  I'm not seeing any support for this.  Does the RangeSlider support this?  If not is anyone aware of alternatives?  Thanks

Comment: You found a way? I am facing the same problem

Comment: @giordy16 I did not find a way using RangeSlider.  What I ended up doing was using the source code of com.google.android.material.slider.BaseSlider as a starting point and rolling out my own solution.